# 400 Bad Request on account or admin login

Tags: nginx

On attempting to login into either a front-end account or admin account I'm hit by:

400 Bad Request
Request Header Or Cookie Too Large
nginx/1.8.0

It's only happened recently but running the latest Craft CMS v2.5.2757 and from looking at the cookies created during login I think it's possibly related to CSRF protection as deleting the top cookie in the list below fixes the issue until you log in again.

[image: Google Console Log]

Running a few other Craft sites on the same staging nGinx server without the same issue, and even the same codebase is running another site without issue.

Any thoughts please?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your nginx `server` block:

```
server {
  ...
  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
  ...
}
```

and restart nginx. The default is 8k. If you have a lot of headers, beefing that value up should resolve it otherwise you may want to play with [`client_header_buffer_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_header_buffer_size) as well.

Comment: FWIW I encountered the exact same problem a few months back and this is precisely what fixed it. 'Twas tricky because it only occurred in production, where there was lots of tracking garbage and many a cookie involved.

Comment: Thanks very much, not seen this before but again it's only on staging (not local or live!). Fixed the issue perfectly :)

Comment: Good deal! nginx is fun but its docs can be lacking ;)